# Logical implication of the form $P\to P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Two logical propositions are given.

$$P:\ good\ books\ are\ not\ cheap\\
Q:\ cheap\ books\ are\ not\ good$$

Now 3 statements are given:

$A:\ P \ implies\ Q\\
B:\ Q\ implies\ P\\
C:\ P\ and\ Q\ are\ equivalent$

Which of these 3 are/is true?

$i)\ Only\ A\\
ii)\ Only\ B\\
iii)\ Only\ C\\
iv)\ All\ of\ A,\ B\ and\ C$

```
Certainly option iii) i.e statement C is true. But I'm confused 
with option iv) also.
```

Does this implication $P\to P$ hold ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option $iv$ is correct here.

P: "if x is a good book, then x is not cheap" is equivalent to  Q: "if x is cheap, then x is not a good book", since each is the **contrapositive** of the other.

$$\text{Recall: }\;P \rightarrow Q \iff \lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P$$

So each implies the other: which is often denoted by $P\iff Q$: this is simply a concise way of saying $(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow P)$.

Stronger get, $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent.

---

Yes, $P\rightarrow P$. This is true of any proposition $P$, since $P \rightarrow P \equiv \lnot P \lor P$, which is a tautology!

Comment: If we "know of" *tautologies*, $p \rightarrow p$ **is** iteself a tautology, without need of the equivalence ...:)

Comment: Of course, @Mauro Nothing I said indicates otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Two statements are equivalent if and only if each implies the other.  So, saying $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent is saying that $P$ implies $Q$ and $Q$ implies $P$.

Also, $P\rightarrow P$ is always true.